# Azure Devops: Trigger Release pipeline on a particular day

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I need some guidance with triggering the release pipeline on a particular day. I know there are few links regarding the same, but it didnt answer my question.

**My Existing Scenario:**
I have a build pipeline. The Build pipeline is triggered by Pull Requests and the Builds which needs to be deployed are always TAGGED.
This TAG is added once the PR is complete and build is created.
For deployment, Release Pipelines are configured to pick up the latest TAGGED Build only from the available build. Currently I am manually triggering this release pipeline on the date of deployment.

**What I tried:**
As per the various articles , I have added a cron scheduler in the yaml based build pipeline which will run on specific date as mentioned in the cron expression. I also added the CD trigger in release pipeline which will deploy the code as soon as the new build is available.

**My Problem:**
The build pipeline is now triggered by cron expression and also by the PR trigger. Due to this, the release pipeline is executed for both cron based and PR based builds.
If i remove the PR based trigger, i will not be able to specify which build should be deployed by TAGGING it.
Could you please suggest how can i have a cron based deployment only along with feasibility to deploy only TAGGED builds.
Any pointers how the pipelines should be configured in such cases?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using Azure Devops Rest API invocation for the pipelines.
I created a azure PAT , got the pipeline definition id and Scheduled the aws lambda using cron expression to invoke the azure release pipeline.

Comment: Please add more details so anyone in future can benefit from it in future